# SQL Server passing variable to a string in a stored proc

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, stored-procedures, parameter

I am trying to concatenate a custom string with a variable that is an int. `Investigation is pending for  ['+ @investigationidout +']`. When I hover the mouse pointer over the first `+` sign it says:

> Incorrect syntax near '+'

Is this possible ?

I need to see something like:

> Investigation is pending for 1234

My query:

```
    EXEC sp_wf_create_notification 
        @processid,
        @vactivityid,
        @vstepid,
        1,
        @vidColumn,
        @vidColumnTable,
        @investigationidout,
        @owner,
        'Pending Investigation',
        'Investigation is pending for  ['+ @investigationidout +'] '
        @nextstepurl,
        @vstatus OUTPUT,
        @verror OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 15):

The parameters supplied to a procedure must be constants or variables.
A function or the output of a function or an expression cannot be used.

You would have to first set a variable with the required expression:

```
declare @investigation varchar(100);
set @investigation = 'Investigation is pending for  ['+ @investigationidout +'] ';

EXEC sp_wf_create_notification 
    @processid,
    @vactivityid,
    @vstepid,
    1,
    @vidColumn,
    @vidColumnTable,
    @investigationidout,
    @owner,
    'Pending Investigation',
    @investigation
    @nextstepurl,
    @vstatus OUTPUT,
    @verror OUTPUT
;
```

For `OUTPUT` variables, don't forget to add `OUTPUT` after its name.

See [MSDN Specify Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189260.aspx):

> The parameter values supplied with a procedure call must be constants or a variable; a function name cannot be used as a parameter value. Variables can be user-defined or system variables such as @@spid.

Answer (score 1):

For example, I did something like this to pass concatenated strings to my stored procedure

```
select top 10 * from sbat

declare @string varchar(max) = 'Rows inserted:' + cast(@@ROWCOUNT as varchar)

exec proc_Log @msg = @string, @tablename = 'STG_SBAT_test'
```